# Trying to make a form that adds number automatically without submit like event listner

Tags: javascript, html, forms

Please help I have done this so far. I want all 6 fiels working how can i do this? This is basically to calculate exam result so as fast help needed.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var a = parseFloat(document.getElementById("txt1").value);
  var b = parseFloat(document.getElementById("txt2").value);
  var c = parseFloat(document.getElementById("txt3").value);
  var d = parseFloat(document.getElementById("txt3").value);
  var e = parseFloat(document.getElementById("txt4").value);
  var f = parseFloat(document.getElementById("txt5").value);
  var g = parseFloat(document.getElementById("txt6").value);
  var g = a + b + c + d + e + f + g;
  // If x = NaN empty variable x
  if (!g) {
    x = '';
  }
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
}
window.onload = function() {
  var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('calc');
  for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    // Listen for input > Call MyFunction
    inputs[i].addEventListener('input', myFunction, false);
  }
};
```

```html
Enter first number:
<input type="text" class="calc" id="txt1" name="text1">Enter second number:
<input type="text" class="calc" id="txt2" name="text2">Enter third numve
<input type="text" class="calc" id="txt3" name="text3">Enter fourth number:
<input type="text" class="calc" id="txt4" name="text4">Enter fifth number:
<input type="text" class="calc" id="txt5" name="text5">Enter sixth number:
<input type="text" class="calc" id="txt6" name="text6">
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: I see you have expanded on my answer from your previous question. It would be nice for you to mark it since you have found the answer useful.

Comment: yeah newtojs help me please

Comment: You need to accept my previous answer first. The point of answering and helping if for you to mark the answer. It helps others find acceptable answers who have a similar issue.

Comment: You're putting the sum into `g`, but then putting `x` into the `demo` DIV.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have more inputs and you have expanded on my previous answer can cut down on the source code by using `getElementsByClassName()` and a `for` loop to add up the inputs.

Don't forget to close your inputs using `/>`. I have also removed the `ID's` as the `class` name and for loop will take care of targeting those elements.

```js
function myFunction() {
var a=0;
var Calc=document.getElementsByClassName('calc');
for(var i=0; i<Calc.length; i++){
 if(parseFloat(Calc[i].value)){
 a=a+parseFloat(Calc[i].value);
 }
}
// If a = NaN empty variable a
if(isNaN(parseFloat(a))){x='';}
// Changed from .innerHTML to .value
document.getElementById("Result").value = a;
}
window.onload=function(){
var inputs=document.getElementsByClassName('calc');
  for(var i=0; i<inputs.length; i++){
    // Listen for input > Call MyFunction
    inputs[i].addEventListener('input',myFunction,false);
  }
};
```

```html
Enter first number: <input type="text" class="calc"/>
Enter second number:<input type="text" class="calc">
Enter third numve <input type="text" class="calc"/>
Enter fourth number:<input type="text" class="calc"/>
Enter fifth number: <input type="text" class="calc"/>
Enter sixth number:<input type="text" class="calc"/>
<!-- Div Removed and input added -->
<input type="text" id="Result"/>
```

> **Request Edit:** Change div element to input for results

If you have any questions about the source code above please leave a comment below and I will get back to you as soon as possible.

I hope this helps. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

```js
function myFunction() {
   Thanks NewTo Js for helping me This is working :)  
var a=0;
var Calc=document.getElementsByClassName('calc');
for(var i=0; i<Calc.length; i++){
 if(parseFloat(Calc[i].value)){
 a=a+parseFloat(Calc[i].value);
 }
}
// If x = NaN empty variable x
if(!a){a='';}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = a;
}
window.onload=function(){
var inputs=document.getElementsByClassName('calc');
  for(var i=0; i<inputs.length; i++){
    // Listen for input > Call MyFunction
    inputs[i].addEventListener('input',myFunction,false);
  }
};
```

```html
Enter first number: <input type="text" class="calc" id="txt1" name="text1">
Enter second number:<input type="text" class="calc" id="txt2" name="text2">
Enter third numve <input type="text" class="calc" id="txt3" name="text3">
Enter fourth number:<input type="text" class="calc" id="txt4" name="text4">
Enter fifth number: <input type="text" class="calc" id="txt5" name="text5">
Enter sixth number:<input type="text" class="calc" id="txt6" name="text6">
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: If it's working, please mark it when the option is available for you to do so.

Comment: NEwToJs  i want the result in input box how do i do so

Comment: NewToJs i want the result in input box how i can i achieve this

Comment: and i want it id because i have many classes for the styling if posssible

Comment: see it in gmail or https://freecharge.in
how i can do this, iam new to js and website design

Comment: how to make input form what above website use

Comment: You can keep the `ID's` if you want them. I removed them for the purpose of the demo and to display clean snippet code. If you have the same css styles for all the inputs you can target the class using `.calc{//styles here}` and it will apply those styles to all the  elements.

Comment: The input on that website uses CSS to hide the border and background of the input and using a parent element with a low opacity / rgba background.

Comment: Use `document.getElementById("Result").value` Example `var MyVal=document.getElementById("Result").value` and `MyVal` will equal to the result/input value.

Comment: i don't know what you are saying could just give a full code please

Comment: What do you mean by `get` the result in the input field? To do what with it?